# Rademacher theorem for Riemannian manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be an open set of $\mathbb R^n $ and let $ ds^2 $ be some metric on $M$. Let $ d $ be the distance induced by $ ds^2 $ on $M$. If $ f $ is a Lipschitz function with respect to $ d $, is it true that $ f $ is differentiable almost everywhere?
The classical Rademacher theorem ensures this fact for Lipschitz function with respect to the standard euclidean norm of $\mathbb R^n $. I think that this fact could be important (if it is true) in connection with several facts in conformal geometry and differential geoemetry. For example i think it is important in the answer of one of my questions '[gradient of a Lipschitz function on a Riemannian manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272103/gradient-of-a-lipschitz-function-on-a-riemannian-manifold)'.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Technical remark: it is very easy to add links to a post with [name of the link](address). This is what I did in your post. (Along with minor LaTeX and capitalization improvements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the very mild assumption that the coefficients $g_{ij}$ of the metric $ds^2$ are locally bounded, on every compactly contained ball $B\Subset M$ we have $d(a,b)\le C|a-b|$ for some constant $C=C(B)$. Therefore, a function that is Lipschitz with respect to $d$ is also Lipschitz on $B$ with respect to the Euclidean metric. The Rademacher theorem applies and tells us that $f$ is differentiable a.e. on $B$, hence differentiable a.e. on $M$.

If you want to consider $g_{ij}$ that are not locally bounded, the result may still be true in some cases, but I'm not sure if you need such metrics in your differential geometry studies.

Comment: The assumption of local boundness is the key fact (trivially satisfied by all metrics that i'm considering). Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What is $|a-b|$ for $a, b \in M$?

Comment: How could a continuous (even differentiable) function on a manifold (think of $g_{ij}$) _not_ be locally-bounded?